# Error fetching data: Request failed with status code 422

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a loginpage and I am having some trouble when i try to login a user. I am Useding Axios to for to make a request, the code work so well when testing it with postman, but when I try runing the code on the client side it will fail with the am trying to login a user by using axios  but I ran throught the error

```
status: 422, statusText: 'UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY
```

```
//Home.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import "./HomePage.css";

const HomePage = () => {
  const { user, token } = useAuth();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });

        if (response && response.data) {
          setData(response.data);
        } else {
          setError("No data received from the server");
        }
        setIsPending(false);
      }  catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error.response);
        setIsPending(false);
        setError(error.message);
      }
      
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [token]);

  const handleStartClick = () => {
    if (!user) {
      navigate("/register");
    } else {
      navigate("/subscribe");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="homepage-container">
      <div className="content-container">
        <h1>Welcome to Box service, {user ? user.username : "Guest"}!</h1>
        {isPending ? (
          <p>Loading data...</p>
        ) : error ? (
          <p>Error fetching data: {error}</p>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {data.length > 0 ? (
              data.map((item) => <p key={item.id}>{item.message}</p>)
            ) : (
              <p>No data available.</p>
            )}
            <button onClick={handleStartClick} className="st-btn">
              GET STARTED
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

please I will really appreciate your help. Thanks

I trying to login a user but when I try runing the code on the client side it will fail with the am trying to login a user by using axios